# Auto select "Try Ubuntu 16.04" in uefi mode

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, uefi, syslinux, isolinux

I need to install Ubuntu 16.04 in uefi mode without keyboard, so I need to auto select Try ubuntu but if I edit isolinux.cfg and syslinux.cfg this has effect only if I boot the usb drive in legacy mode. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answering your question about auto-selecting 'Try Ubuntu'

The Ubuntu live system boots via `grub` in UEFI mode. So you should edit the the grub configuration file(s). This file may be in different locations depending on how you created the boot drive.

- If **created by an extracting tool** (for example [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/)), there is probably one partition with a FAT32 file system in the USB pendrive, and the file is located at

  ```
  boot/grub/grub.cfg
  ```

  in this FAT32 file system.

  If it is a live-only system, you must probably boot from another drive to edit the file, because the file system is mounted read-only, but if it is a persistent live system, you should be able to edit the file, also when booted from the system itself.
- If a **persistent live system created by [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)**, you should edit the file `grub.cfg`, that you find in the third partition labeled 'usbboot' in the USB pendrive.

  ```
  sudo lsblk -f
  sudo lsblk -m
  ```

  Identify the device letter **`x`** and mount the partition,

  ```
  sudo mount /dev/sdx3 /mnt
  ```

  for example **`b`**

  ```
  sudo mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt
  ```

  list the file

  ```
  ls -l /mnt/boot/grub/grub.cfg
  ```

  and edit the file

  ```
  nano /mnt/boot/grub/grub.cfg
  ```
- If it is a **cloned** system, made by for example the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator, Disks, mkusb, `dd`, there will be a read-only ISO 9660 file system, and it is read-only. So you cannot edit the file.

### But the installer expects a dialogue

But there is a dialogue in the installer Ubiquity, and I think it is difficult to run it without interaction.

### Clone an installed system

So maybe you should clone [an installed system, that can boot both in UEFI and BIOS mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS), and afterwards, when booted into it, install the desktop environment, that you want, `ubuntu-desktop` to get standard Ubuntu with Unity.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I keep this info in mind for the future, for this time I found an old usb keyboard that simplify the situation!